# float and round function in sql

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT ROUND(1.84037E-33,1) from my_table
```

Result is 0.

But i want to get **`1.84037`** (the data type is float.)

What do I need to do?

Thanks.

Comment: 1.84037E-33 is notation for 1.84037 * 10^-33 or 0.000000000000000000000000000000000184037

In this case round is correct to round to 0.

Comment: I would like to display 1.8403. So how can i do that. Thanks ....

Comment: Technical what you are asking is bit complicated. Use LEFT function to get data you want.

Comment: It appears you want to extract the mantissa of the value.  Even so, your question is ambiguous.   Let me ask.   What answer do you expect when the value is  18.4037E-34?   What answer do you expect when the value is  18.4037?   What answer do you expect when the value is  1.84037e+4?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(1.84037E-33 AS NVARCHAR), 0, 
            CHARINDEX('e', CAST(1.84037E-33 AS NVARCHAR))) 
            AS FLOAT)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by 1E33 before rounding.  (Do you even want to round?)

```
SELECT ROUND(1.84037E-33 * 1E33,1) from my_table
```